# Getting missing positional argument error when trying to define middleware in Django

Tags: django-middleware

I am trying to come up with my first middleware of my own in a Django 1.10 project. And currently running into the following error

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'get_response'

I have defined the middleware in a `middleware.py` like this:

from zeon.utils import RequestLogThread

```
class StartRestEndPointMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        request.request_log_id = RequestLogThread('send_contact', request.data).start()

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

I am lost trying to figure out what's wrong, since everything seems to be in accordance with the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/). I would really appreciate any hint.

*UPDATE:*
I place it into middle_classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'zeon.middleware.StartRestEndPointMiddleWare',
]
```

Comment: Are you placing it into the `MIDDLEWARE` dictionary or into the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` dictionary?

Comment: I've updated the question in accordance with your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django changed the way middleware classes worked in 1.10. New-style middleware classes belong in the `MIDDLEWARE` list, like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'zeon.middleware.StartRestEndPointMiddleWare',
]
```

When you put your middleware into `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, it's being treated as an old-style middleware, which works differently. A better error message might have made this more clear.

Comment: and what about the rest of middleware? Should I leave them in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES ` and move only the user-defined middleware to `MIDDLEWARES` ? Or I should place everything to `MIDDLEWARES`?

Comment: Looks like it should be `MIDDLEWARE`, not `MIDDLEWARES`

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan: Thanks, fixed. All of the built-in middlewares support both, so you can probably move everything over to `MIDDLEWARE`. You can't have both `MIDDLEWARE` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` at the same time.